# What does < .... > Do in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

What does the following code do? What is <...> notation?

```
<Global.System.Serializable(),_  
 Global.System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("GetTypedTableSchema")>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the notation for applying [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating metadata, or declarative information, with code (assemblies, types, methods, properties, and so forth). After an attribute is associated with a program entity, the attribute can be queried at run time by using a technique called reflection.

And:

> Attributes can be placed on most any declaration, though a specific attribute might restrict the types of declarations on which it is valid. In C#, you specify an attribute by placing the name of the attribute, enclosed in square brackets ([]), above the declaration of the entity to which it applies. In Visual Basic, an attribute is enclosed in angle brackets (< >). It must appear immediately before the element to which it is applied, on the same line.

---

In your code, you are marking the type (or method or property) as serializable and that the XmlSchemaProviderAttribute for the type is set with `"GetTypedTableSchema"`.

These two are metadata that helps with serializing the type.